# Pass line number and first word to variables with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to pass the "$1" and "NR" values, of the script below, respectively to the variables "word" and "line", instead of printing them.

```
    awk '\
    BEGIN { \
    s = 0; \
    } \
    { \
    s += $2; \
    if (s >= 87) { \
    print $1; \
    print NR; \
    exit; \
    } \
    }' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let `awk` dislay the settings that you want (you do not need backslashes between the `awk` quotes).

```
awk '
BEGIN { s = 0; }
{
   s += $2;
   if (s >= 87) {
      print "word=\"" $1 "\"";
      print "line=" NR;
      exit;
   }
}' file
```

You want the output processed. You can do this with

```
source <(awk '
BEGIN { s = 0; }
{
   s += $2;
   if (s >= 87) {
      print "word=\"" $1 "\"";
      print "line=" NR;
      exit;
   }
}' file)
```

EDIT: See comments: the awk command can be shorter. I also replaced the `source` with a `read`:

```
read -r word line < <(awk ' {s += $2} s >= 87 { print $1 " " NR; exit; }' file )
```

Comment: You don't need semi-colons at the end of lines either - those trailing semi-colons are as useful as the trailing backslashes you removed. You don't need the BEGIN section either.

Comment: Further, you can simplify it to `awk '{s+=$2}; s >= 87 {print $1; print NR; exit}' file`.